# How to send email through apex in salesforce?

Tags: apex, query

```
 public static AggregateResult[] Get_Officer()
    {
       Date startDate = Date.today().addMonths(-1);
       startDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),1);
       Date endDate = startDate;
       Integer days = Date.daysInMonth(endDate.year(), endDate.month());
       endDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),days);
       AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT Loan_Officer_1a__c, Name, Phone, Starting_Credit_Score__c, 
                            Status, Enrolled_On__c, Est_Re_Pull_Date__c, Realtor_Name__c 
                            FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate >=: startDate AND CreatedDate <=: endDate Group By Loan_Officer_1a__c,Name, Phone, Starting_Credit_Score__c, 
                            Status, Enrolled_On__c, Est_Re_Pull_Date__c, Realtor_Name__c];

         return groupedResults;  
   }
```

Error is:

> Illegal assignment from Lead to AggregateResult

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to accomplish and what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to write for loop on AggregateResult to email leads on respective Loan Officer .(Loan_Officer_1a_c)

Comment: I have got an error (Illegal assignment from Lead to AggregateResult)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is because you are using the same variable name twice in the same scope:
`for(AggregateResult leads : groupedResults) {`
Here you declared the `leads` variable to be an `AggregateResult`.

`leads = [select Loan_Officer_1a__c from Lead Where Name = 'Muhammad Jawwad' Limit 1];`
Here you are trying to assign the same `leads` variable a `List<Lead>`.
So that's your error.

But there are some more issues with your code.
Salesforce best practice is to not perform queries or callouts from within a loop. You can see a list of best practices [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).
So you want to do a few things:

1. Get the `List<Lead>` before your loop (and give it a different name). This will also solve your other problem.
2. Get your `EmailTemplate` before your loop.
3. Create a `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` before your loop. Then, inside your loop, add each message you create to the list.
4. After your loop you can send your entire list of messages.